# Linux Container on Windows Server Running as Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, azure, windows-server-2016, linux-containers

I'm new to containers. Currently, I have an instance of Windows Server 2016 running as Azure Virtual Machine. Is it or will it still be impossible to set up a Linux Container on it?

I know that instances of Azure VM are already a kind of Hyper-V instance so that creating a virtual machine on them is not feasible.

Then, recently [Microsoft announced](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloud/2017/04/18/dockercon-2017-powering-new-linux-innovations-with-hyper-v-isolation-and-windows-server/) Windows Server 2016 will soon get native Linux Container support. However, it seems that the feature is enabled with Hyper-V Container isolation, so I think adding a Linux Container to the server will be still impossible in future.

Is my understanding correct, and if correct, what will be practical merits of this new function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that instances of Azure VM are already a kind of Hyper-V
>   instance so that creating a virtual machine on them is not feasible.

For now, we **can't** test the new feature in Azure VM. But in my opinion, I agree with you,
because we can't install Hyper-V on Azure VM (by default).

I think we should wait for some time, then test the new feature in Azure VM.

Answer (score 1):

> However, it seems that the feature is enabled with Hyper-V Container isolation

This is correct. Native Linux Container support is built on Hyper-V Isolation, which is dependent on Hyper-V being enabled.  Historically, "nested virtualization" hasn't been possible within Azure VMs.

However, Azure will enable nested virtualization (and hyperthreading) in [the upcoming Dv3 and Ev3 VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/price-reductions-on-l-series-and-announcing-next-generation-hyper-threaded-virtual-machines/). This should allow Hyper-V Containers to run within these VM families.  Corey Sanders has a [quick video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Tuesdays-With-Corey/Tuesdays-with-Corey-M-Series-and-Nested-Virtualization-on-Azure) showing a demo.